# If I using firebase realtime database, Do I need to use pagination?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, pagination

If I using firebase realtime database, Do I need to use pagination?

if the answer is yes, how could I modify my code?

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Campsite");

Query query = reference.orderByChild("country").equalTo(country);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if(seatch_bar.getText().toString().equals("")){
            camperSiteModel.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                CamperSiteModel camperSiteModel1 = snapshot.getValue(CamperSiteModel.class);

                camperSiteModel.add(camperSiteModel1);
            }
            camperSiteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

I have try to use this ways, but... is it cannot use limit? Because I just try to this methods.

`DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Campsite").orderByKey().startAt().limitToFirst();`

Comment: There is no requirement to use pagination with the Firebase Realtime Database. But this seems like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you asking about pagination? What doesn't work about the code you shard?

Comment: As also Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his comment, it's not mandatory to use pagination. But I don't understand what do you mean by "is it cannot use limit"? What's wrong with the code in your question? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm just afraid that when the amount of data, it will cause the app to read too slowly

Comment: @AlexMamo  I'm just afraid that when the amount of data, it will cause the app to read too slowly

Comment: In that case, what's wrong with the code in your question?

Comment: If you think you'll be reading too much data, you can [limit how many nodes are returned](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data). If you think some users may also want to see more data than the limit, [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+pagination) is a great way to address that. But none of us here can determine whether your app needs pagination - that is up to you to decide.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Because I have develop similar facebook app, it's can show any user post status, so do I need to use pagination? or just set limit?

Comment: The amount of data you have is not really relevant to the question - what is relevant is the amount of data you present to the user or the amount of data you need to process at a time. If you have 100,000 campsites, do you really want to load in and display 100,000 campsites to the user? Probably not - you will want a limited 'snapshot' of data that's applicable to that user; perhaps campsites within 50 miles of a point or campsites in Colorado that have internet. So there's really no way to answer the question because it depends on what data you want displayed.